# Dropping dates except specific year from panel data

Tags: r

I have panel data from 2000 to 2017. I want to select rows which are 2005.

Amazingly

```
mydata <- subset(mydata, select= c(mydata$Year>="2005"))
```

did not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe try `mydata <- subset(mydata, Year == 2005))` ?

Comment: I like the data.table solution:

   `library(data.table)
    as.data.table(df)[year>=2005]`

Only 2005

    `library(data.table)
    as.data.table(df)[year==2005]`

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed the data is in date or numeric format.

```
   library(dplyr)
    df%>% 
      filter(year>=2005)
```

Only 2005:

```
library(dplyr)
flights %>% 
  filter(year==2005)
```

Comment: Please avoid answering obvious duplicates.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know.

Comment: No problem, here is the list of [canonical Q&As for R](https://github.com/r-public/HammeR/blob/master/Canonicals.md), I use them to suggest a link in the comments if I think the post is a duplicate. e.g.: "Possible duplicate [link]"

Comment: Will do so going forward. Thanks!